# Jazz music about that "music will always be there for me"

Tags: identify-this-song, jazz

I have an alarm app that plays "random" music from Spotify each time. Recently I woke up to a jazz song that I liked, but I have no way finding out what it is - the alarm doesn't history. I was still half asleep when I shot it down, but these are the things I remember:

- It's a calm jazz (or jazz-like) song, sang by a woman. The dominant (maybe only) instrument is piano, I don't remember any other.
- The lyrics is something like >>I felt lonely, [I don't remember this part much, maybe about missing you], "but then I realized // that music will always be (there? ) for me <<, or something alike
- I remember the main theme, it's like this: >> mi mi mi so la-so-re <<, with rhythm >>ta ti ti ta [pause] ti-ti-taa<< (last three notes joined). For example for the lyrics "I woke up and I realized" belongs to these sounds - but most of the song way along this line.

Does this ring a bell for you? I'd be really happy if I could find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

It was **Music; My Love** from **Marye Lobb** ([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50O14Km-CRI), [Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/653ajGsqtiYHCrlUY7DaCr?si=ocaKIBQWRTq0YeohNQQSsg)).